# How to remove extra characters from the end of email addresses

Tags: javascript

I'd like to remove extra characters from the end of email addresses, for example the "www" from  xy@gmail.comwww

I created a function which gets the value from an input field and then I tried to use regular expression to check the email pattern, but it won't remove the additional characters from the end of the email address.

```js
const txtContent = document.getElementById("txtContent");
function checkEmails() {
  const temp = txtContent.value;
  // Match email pattern
  const regexp = /([A-Za-z0-9._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/gi;
  // Get the email by matching against the regexp
  const emailsRaw = temp.match(regexp);
  // Remove duplicate emails
  const emails = [];
  if (emailsRaw != null) {
    emailsRaw.forEach(email => {
      // Check if the email address is already included in the emails array
      if (!emails.includes(email)) {
        emails.push(email);
      }
    });
  }
  return emails;
}
console.log(checkEmails())
```

```html
<textarea id="txtContent">aa@aaa.comwww</textarea>
```

Comment: Can you try this regex instead ? const regexp = /([A-Za-z0-9._-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)^/gi;

Comment: How do you know that `.com` is a valid TLD but `.comwww` isn't?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please do yourself that in the future

Comment: There are over 1500 valid TLDs, you're possibly going to introduce problems by regexing this

Comment: Your regex doesn't recognize a ton of valid email addresses. What about  `foo@example.gv.at`? A totally valid address, which won't be recognized by your regex. What you want is impossible with regex only unless you include a list of valid TLD in your regex ...

Comment: How do you end up with an extra `www` at the end of an email address anyway? Why not trust your user that they wrote the correct address?

Comment: @Johan did you [try it](https://jsbin.com/foqaneduma/1/edit?html,js,console,output)? Spoiler: it does not work. Further spoiler, it is impossible for it to work since it requires there is text before the start of the line. Which cannot be satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

```js
// tlds from https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt
const tlds = ['AAA', 'AARP', 'ABARTH', 'ABB', 'ABBOTT', 'ABBVIE', 'ABC', 'ABLE', 'ABOGADO', 'ABUDHABI', 'AC', 'ACADEMY', 'ACCENTURE', 'ACCOUNTANT', 'ACCOUNTANTS', 'ACO', 'ACTOR', 'AD', 'ADS', 'ADULT', 'AE', 'AEG', 'AERO', 'AETNA', 'AF', 'AFL', 'AFRICA', 'AG', 'AGAKHAN', 'AGENCY', 'AI', 'AIG', 'AIRBUS', 'AIRFORCE', 'AIRTEL', 'AKDN', 'AL', 'ALFAROMEO', 'ALIBABA', 'ALIPAY', 'ALLFINANZ', 'ALLSTATE', 'ALLY', 'ALSACE', 'ALSTOM', 'AM', 'AMAZON', 'AMERICANEXPRESS', 'AMERICANFAMILY', 'AMEX', 'AMFAM', 'AMICA', 'AMSTERDAM', 'ANALYTICS', 'ANDROID', 'ANQUAN', 'ANZ', 'AO', 'AOL', 'APARTMENTS', 'APP', 'APPLE', 'AQ', 'AQUARELLE', 'AR', 'ARAB', 'ARAMCO', 'ARCHI', 'ARMY', 'ARPA', 'ART', 'ARTE', 'AS', 'ASDA', 'ASIA', 'ASSOCIATES', 'AT', 'ATHLETA', 'ATTORNEY', 'AU', 'AUCTION', 'AUDI', 'AUDIBLE', 'AUDIO', 'AUSPOST', 'AUTHOR', 'AUTO', 'AUTOS', 'AVIANCA', 'AW', 'AWS', 'AX', 'AXA', 'AZ', 'AZURE', 'BA', 'BABY', 'BAIDU', 'BANAMEX', 'BANANAREPUBLIC', 'BAND', 'BANK', 'BAR', 'BARCELONA', 'BARCLAYCARD', 'BARCLAYS', 'BAREFOOT', 'BARGAINS', 'BASEBALL', 'BASKETBALL', 'BAUHAUS', 'BAYERN', 'BB', 'BBC', 'BBT', 'BBVA', 'BCG', 'BCN', 'BD', 'BE', 'BEATS', 'BEAUTY', 'BEER', 'BENTLEY', 'BERLIN', 'BEST', 'BESTBUY', 'BET', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BHARTI', 'BI', 'BIBLE', 'BID', 'BIKE', 'BING', 'BINGO', 'BIO', 'BIZ', 'BJ', 'BLACK', 'BLACKFRIDAY', 'BLOCKBUSTER', 'BLOG', 'BLOOMBERG', 'BLUE', 'BM', 'BMS', 'BMW', 'BN', 'BNPPARIBAS', 'BO', 'BOATS', 'BOEHRINGER', 'BOFA', 'BOM', 'BOND', 'BOO', 'BOOK', 'BOOKING', 'BOSCH', 'BOSTIK', 'BOSTON', 'BOT', 'BOUTIQUE', 'BOX', 'BR', 'BRADESCO', 'BRIDGESTONE', 'BROADWAY', 'BROKER', 'BROTHER', 'BRUSSELS', 'BS', 'BT', 'BUILD', 'BUILDERS', 'BUSINESS', 'BUY', 'BUZZ', 'BV', 'BW', 'BY', 'BZ', 'BZH', 'CA', 'CAB', 'CAFE', 'CAL', 'CALL', 'CALVINKLEIN', 'CAM', 'CAMERA', 'CAMP', 'CANON', 'CAPETOWN', 'CAPITAL', 'CAPITALONE', 'CAR', 'CARAVAN', 'CARDS', 'CARE', 'CAREER', 'CAREERS', 'CARS', 'CASA', 'CASE', 'CASH', 'CASINO', 'CAT', 'CATERING', 'CATHOLIC', 'CBA', 'CBN', 'CBRE', 'CBS', 'CC', 'CD', 'CENTER', 'CEO', 'CERN', 'CF', 'CFA', 'CFD', 'CG', 'CH', 'CHANEL', 'CHANNEL', 'CHARITY', 'CHASE', 'CHAT', 'CHEAP', 'CHINTAI', 'CHRISTMAS', 'CHROME', 'CHURCH', 'CI', 'CIPRIANI', 'CIRCLE', 'CISCO', 'CITADEL', 'CITI', 'CITIC', 'CITY', 'CITYEATS', 'CK', 'CL', 'CLAIMS', 'CLEANING', 'CLICK', 'CLINIC', 'CLINIQUE', 'CLOTHING', 'CLOUD', 'CLUB', 'CLUBMED', 'CM', 'CN', 'CO', 'COACH', 'CODES', 'COFFEE', 'COLLEGE', 'COLOGNE', 'COM', 'COMCAST', 'COMMBANK', 'COMMUNITY', 'COMPANY', 'COMPARE', 'COMPUTER', 'COMSEC', 'CONDOS', 'CONSTRUCTION', 'CONSULTING', 'CONTACT', 'CONTRACTORS', 'COOKING', 'COOKINGCHANNEL', 'COOL', 'COOP', 'CORSICA', 'COUNTRY', 'COUPON', 'COUPONS', 'COURSES', 'CPA', 'CR', 'CREDIT', 'CREDITCARD', 'CREDITUNION', 'CRICKET', 'CROWN', 'CRS', 'CRUISE', 'CRUISES', 'CU', 'CUISINELLA', 'CV', 'CW', 'CX', 'CY', 'CYMRU', 'CYOU', 'CZ', 'DABUR', 'DAD', 'DANCE', 'DATA', 'DATE', 'DATING', 'DATSUN', 'DAY', 'DCLK', 'DDS', 'DE', 'DEAL', 'DEALER', 'DEALS', 'DEGREE', 'DELIVERY', 'DELL', 'DELOITTE', 'DELTA', 'DEMOCRAT', 'DENTAL', 'DENTIST', 'DESI', 'DESIGN', 'DEV', 'DHL', 'DIAMONDS', 'DIET', 'DIGITAL', 'DIRECT', 'DIRECTORY', 'DISCOUNT', 'DISCOVER', 'DISH', 'DIY', 'DJ', 'DK', 'DM', 'DNP', 'DO', 'DOCS', 'DOCTOR', 'DOG', 'DOMAINS', 'DOT', 'DOWNLOAD', 'DRIVE', 'DTV', 'DUBAI', 'DUNLOP', 'DUPONT', 'DURBAN', 'DVAG', 'DVR', 'DZ', 'EARTH', 'EAT', 'EC', 'ECO', 'EDEKA', 'EDU', 'EDUCATION', 'EE', 'EG', 'EMAIL', 'EMERCK', 'ENERGY', 'ENGINEER', 'ENGINEERING', 'ENTERPRISES', 'EPSON', 'EQUIPMENT', 'ER', 'ERICSSON', 'ERNI', 'ES', 'ESQ', 'ESTATE', 'ET', 'ETISALAT', 'EU', 'EUROVISION', 'EUS', 'EVENTS', 'EXCHANGE', 'EXPERT', 'EXPOSED', 'EXPRESS', 'EXTRASPACE', 'FAGE', 'FAIL', 'FAIRWINDS', 'FAITH', 'FAMILY', 'FAN', 'FANS', 'FARM', 'FARMERS', 'FASHION', 'FAST', 'FEDEX', 'FEEDBACK', 'FERRARI', 'FERRERO', 'FI', 'FIAT', 'FIDELITY', 'FIDO', 'FILM', 'FINAL', 'FINANCE', 'FINANCIAL', 'FIRE', 'FIRESTONE', 'FIRMDALE', 'FISH', 'FISHING', 'FIT', 'FITNESS', 'FJ', 'FK', 'FLICKR', 'FLIGHTS', 'FLIR', 'FLORIST', 'FLOWERS', 'FLY', 'FM', 'FO', 'FOO', 'FOOD', 'FOODNETWORK', 'FOOTBALL', 'FORD', 'FOREX', 'FORSALE', 'FORUM', 'FOUNDATION', 'FOX', 'FR', 'FREE', 'FRESENIUS', 'FRL', 'FROGANS', 'FRONTDOOR', 'FRONTIER', 'FTR', 'FUJITSU', 'FUN', 'FUND', 'FURNITURE', 'FUTBOL', 'FYI', 'GA', 'GAL', 'GALLERY', 'GALLO', 'GALLUP', 'GAME', 'GAMES', 'GAP', 'GARDEN', 'GAY', 'GB', 'GBIZ', 'GD', 'GDN', 'GE', 'GEA', 'GENT', 'GENTING', 'GEORGE', 'GF', 'GG', 'GGEE', 'GH', 'GI', 'GIFT', 'GIFTS', 'GIVES', 'GIVING', 'GL', 'GLASS', 'GLE', 'GLOBAL', 'GLOBO', 'GM', 'GMAIL', 'GMBH', 'GMO', 'GMX', 'GN', 'GODADDY', 'GOLD', 'GOLDPOINT', 'GOLF', 'GOO', 'GOODYEAR', 'GOOG', 'GOOGLE', 'GOP', 'GOT', 'GOV', 'GP', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GRAINGER', 'GRAPHICS', 'GRATIS', 'GREEN', 'GRIPE', 'GROCERY', 'GROUP', 'GS', 'GT', 'GU', 'GUARDIAN', 'GUCCI', 'GUGE', 'GUIDE', 'GUITARS', 'GURU', 'GW', 'GY', 'HAIR', 'HAMBURG', 'HANGOUT', 'HAUS', 'HBO', 'HDFC', 'HDFCBANK', 'HEALTH', 'HEALTHCARE', 'HELP', 'HELSINKI', 'HERE', 'HERMES', 'HGTV', 'HIPHOP', 'HISAMITSU', 'HITACHI', 'HIV', 'HK', 'HKT', 'HM', 'HN', 'HOCKEY', 'HOLDINGS', 'HOLIDAY', 'HOMEDEPOT', 'HOMEGOODS', 'HOMES', 'HOMESENSE', 'HONDA', 'HORSE', 'HOSPITAL', 'HOST', 'HOSTING', 'HOT', 'HOTELES', 'HOTELS', 'HOTMAIL', 'HOUSE', 'HOW', 'HR', 'HSBC', 'HT', 'HU', 'HUGHES', 'HYATT', 'HYUNDAI', 'IBM', 'ICBC', 'ICE', 'ICU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IEEE', 'IFM', 'IKANO', 'IL', 'IM', 'IMAMAT', 'IMDB', 'IMMO', 'IMMOBILIEN', 'IN', 'INC', 'INDUSTRIES', 'INFINITI', 'INFO', 'ING', 'INK', 'INSTITUTE', 'INSURANCE', 'INSURE', 'INT', 'INTERNATIONAL', 'INTUIT', 'INVESTMENTS', 'IO', 'IPIRANGA', 'IQ', 'IR', 'IRISH', 'IS', 'ISMAILI', 'IST', 'ISTANBUL', 'IT', 'ITAU', 'ITV', 'JAGUAR', 'JAVA', 'JCB', 'JE', 'JEEP', 'JETZT', 'JEWELRY', 'JIO', 'JLL', 'JM', 'JMP', 'JNJ', 'JO', 'JOBS', 'JOBURG', 'JOT', 'JOY', 'JP', 'JPMORGAN', 'JPRS', 'JUEGOS', 'JUNIPER', 'KAUFEN', 'KDDI', 'KE', 'KERRYHOTELS', 'KERRYLOGISTICS', 'KERRYPROPERTIES', 'KFH', 'KG', 'KH', 'KI', 'KIA', 'KIDS', 'KIM', 'KINDER', 'KINDLE', 'KITCHEN', 'KIWI', 'KM', 'KN', 'KOELN', 'KOMATSU', 'KOSHER', 'KP', 'KPMG', 'KPN', 'KR', 'KRD', 'KRED', 'KUOKGROUP', 'KW', 'KY', 'KYOTO', 'KZ', 'LA', 'LACAIXA', 'LAMBORGHINI', 'LAMER', 'LANCASTER', 'LANCIA', 'LAND', 'LANDROVER', 'LANXESS', 'LASALLE', 'LAT', 'LATINO', 'LATROBE', 'LAW', 'LAWYER', 'LB', 'LC', 'LDS', 'LEASE', 'LECLERC', 'LEFRAK', 'LEGAL', 'LEGO', 'LEXUS', 'LGBT', 'LI', 'LIDL', 'LIFE', 'LIFEINSURANCE', 'LIFESTYLE', 'LIGHTING', 'LIKE', 'LILLY', 'LIMITED', 'LIMO', 'LINCOLN', 'LINDE', 'LINK', 'LIPSY', 'LIVE', 'LIVING', 'LK', 'LLC', 'LLP', 'LOAN', 'LOANS', 'LOCKER', 'LOCUS', 'LOL', 'LONDON', 'LOTTE', 'LOTTO', 'LOVE', 'LPL', 'LPLFINANCIAL', 'LR', 'LS', 'LT', 'LTD', 'LTDA', 'LU', 'LUNDBECK', 'LUXE', 'LUXURY', 'LV', 'LY', 'MA', 'MACYS', 'MADRID', 'MAIF', 'MAISON', 'MAKEUP', 'MAN', 'MANAGEMENT', 'MANGO', 'MAP', 'MARKET', 'MARKETING', 'MARKETS', 'MARRIOTT', 'MARSHALLS', 'MASERATI', 'MATTEL', 'MBA', 'MC', 'MCKINSEY', 'MD', 'ME', 'MED', 'MEDIA', 'MEET', 'MELBOURNE', 'MEME', 'MEMORIAL', 'MEN', 'MENU', 'MERCKMSD', 'MG', 'MH', 'MIAMI', 'MICROSOFT', 'MIL', 'MINI', 'MINT', 'MIT', 'MITSUBISHI', 'MK', 'ML', 'MLB', 'MLS', 'MM', 'MMA', 'MN', 'MO', 'MOBI', 'MOBILE', 'MODA', 'MOE', 'MOI', 'MOM', 'MONASH', 'MONEY', 'MONSTER', 'MORMON', 'MORTGAGE', 'MOSCOW', 'MOTO', 'MOTORCYCLES', 'MOV', 'MOVIE', 'MP', 'MQ', 'MR', 'MS', 'MSD', 'MT', 'MTN', 'MTR', 'MU', 'MUSEUM', 'MUSIC', 'MUTUAL', 'MV', 'MW', 'MX', 'MY', 'MZ', 'NA', 'NAB', 'NAGOYA', 'NAME', 'NATURA', 'NAVY', 'NBA', 'NC', 'NE', 'NEC', 'NET', 'NETBANK', 'NETFLIX', 'NETWORK', 'NEUSTAR', 'NEW', 'NEWS', 'NEXT', 'NEXTDIRECT', 'NEXUS', 'NF', 'NFL', 'NG', 'NGO', 'NHK', 'NI', 'NICO', 'NIKE', 'NIKON', 'NINJA', 'NISSAN', 'NISSAY', 'NL', 'NO', 'NOKIA', 'NORTHWESTERNMUTUAL', 'NORTON', 'NOW', 'NOWRUZ', 'NOWTV', 'NP', 'NR', 'NRA', 'NRW', 'NTT', 'NU', 'NYC', 'NZ', 'OBI', 'OBSERVER', 'OFFICE', 'OKINAWA', 'OLAYAN', 'OLAYANGROUP', 'OLDNAVY', 'OLLO', 'OM', 'OMEGA', 'ONE', 'ONG', 'ONL', 'ONLINE', 'OOO', 'OPEN', 'ORACLE', 'ORANGE', 'ORG', 'ORGANIC', 'ORIGINS', 'OSAKA', 'OTSUKA', 'OTT', 'OVH', 'PA', 'PAGE', 'PANASONIC', 'PARIS', 'PARS', 'PARTNERS', 'PARTS', 'PARTY', 'PASSAGENS', 'PAY', 'PCCW', 'PE', 'PET', 'PF', 'PFIZER', 'PG', 'PH', 'PHARMACY', 'PHD', 'PHILIPS', 'PHONE', 'PHOTO', 'PHOTOGRAPHY', 'PHOTOS', 'PHYSIO', 'PICS', 'PICTET', 'PICTURES', 'PID', 'PIN', 'PING', 'PINK', 'PIONEER', 'PIZZA', 'PK', 'PL', 'PLACE', 'PLAY', 'PLAYSTATION', 'PLUMBING', 'PLUS', 'PM', 'PN', 'PNC', 'POHL', 'POKER', 'POLITIE', 'PORN', 'POST', 'PR', 'PRAMERICA', 'PRAXI', 'PRESS', 'PRIME', 'PRO', 'PROD', 'PRODUCTIONS', 'PROF', 'PROGRESSIVE', 'PROMO', 'PROPERTIES', 'PROPERTY', 'PROTECTION', 'PRU', 'PRUDENTIAL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PUB', 'PW', 'PWC', 'PY', 'QA', 'QPON', 'QUEBEC', 'QUEST', 'RACING', 'RADIO', 'RE', 'READ', 'REALESTATE', 'REALTOR', 'REALTY', 'RECIPES', 'RED', 'REDSTONE', 'REDUMBRELLA', 'REHAB', 'REISE', 'REISEN', 'REIT', 'RELIANCE', 'REN', 'RENT', 'RENTALS', 'REPAIR', 'REPORT', 'REPUBLICAN', 'REST', 'RESTAURANT', 'REVIEW', 'REVIEWS', 'REXROTH', 'RICH', 'RICHARDLI', 'RICOH', 'RIL', 'RIO', 'RIP', 'RO', 'ROCHER', 'ROCKS', 'RODEO', 'ROGERS', 'ROOM', 'RS', 'RSVP', 'RU', 'RUGBY', 'RUHR', 'RUN', 'RW', 'RWE', 'RYUKYU', 'SA', 'SAARLAND', 'SAFE', 'SAFETY', 'SAKURA', 'SALE', 'SALON', 'SAMSCLUB', 'SAMSUNG', 'SANDVIK', 'SANDVIKCOROMANT', 'SANOFI', 'SAP', 'SARL', 'SAS', 'SAVE', 'SAXO', 'SB', 'SBI', 'SBS', 'SC', 'SCA', 'SCB', 'SCHAEFFLER', 'SCHMIDT', 'SCHOLARSHIPS', 'SCHOOL', 'SCHULE', 'SCHWARZ', 'SCIENCE', 'SCOT', 'SD', 'SE', 'SEARCH', 'SEAT', 'SECURE', 'SECURITY', 'SEEK', 'SELECT', 'SENER', 'SERVICES', 'SEVEN', 'SEW', 'SEX', 'SEXY', 'SFR', 'SG', 'SH', 'SHANGRILA', 'SHARP', 'SHAW', 'SHELL', 'SHIA', 'SHIKSHA', 'SHOES', 'SHOP', 'SHOPPING', 'SHOUJI', 'SHOW', 'SHOWTIME', 'SI', 'SILK', 'SINA', 'SINGLES', 'SITE', 'SJ', 'SK', 'SKI', 'SKIN', 'SKY', 'SKYPE', 'SL', 'SLING', 'SM', 'SMART', 'SMILE', 'SN', 'SNCF', 'SO', 'SOCCER', 'SOCIAL', 'SOFTBANK', 'SOFTWARE', 'SOHU', 'SOLAR', 'SOLUTIONS', 'SONG', 'SONY', 'SOY', 'SPA', 'SPACE', 'SPORT', 'SPOT', 'SR', 'SRL', 'SS', 'ST', 'STADA', 'STAPLES', 'STAR', 'STATEBANK', 'STATEFARM', 'STC', 'STCGROUP', 'STOCKHOLM', 'STORAGE', 'STORE', 'STREAM', 'STUDIO', 'STUDY', 'STYLE', 'SU', 'SUCKS', 'SUPPLIES', 'SUPPLY', 'SUPPORT', 'SURF', 'SURGERY', 'SUZUKI', 'SV', 'SWATCH', 'SWISS', 'SX', 'SY', 'SYDNEY', 'SYSTEMS', 'SZ', 'TAB', 'TAIPEI', 'TALK', 'TAOBAO', 'TARGET', 'TATAMOTORS', 'TATAR', 'TATTOO', 'TAX', 'TAXI', 'TC', 'TCI', 'TD', 'TDK', 'TEAM', 'TECH', 'TECHNOLOGY', 'TEL', 'TEMASEK', 'TENNIS', 'TEVA', 'TF', 'TG', 'TH', 'THD', 'THEATER', 'THEATRE', 'TIAA', 'TICKETS', 'TIENDA', 'TIFFANY', 'TIPS', 'TIRES', 'TIROL', 'TJ', 'TJMAXX', 'TJX', 'TK', 'TKMAXX', 'TL', 'TM', 'TMALL', 'TN', 'TO', 'TODAY', 'TOKYO', 'TOOLS', 'TOP', 'TORAY', 'TOSHIBA', 'TOTAL', 'TOURS', 'TOWN', 'TOYOTA', 'TOYS', 'TR', 'TRADE', 'TRADING', 'TRAINING', 'TRAVEL', 'TRAVELCHANNEL', 'TRAVELERS', 'TRAVELERSINSURANCE', 'TRUST', 'TRV', 'TT', 'TUBE', 'TUI', 'TUNES', 'TUSHU', 'TV', 'TVS', 'TW', 'TZ', 'UA', 'UBANK', 'UBS', 'UG', 'UK', 'UNICOM', 'UNIVERSITY', 'UNO', 'UOL', 'UPS', 'US', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VA', 'VACATIONS', 'VANA', 'VANGUARD', 'VC', 'VE', 'VEGAS', 'VENTURES', 'VERISIGN', 'VERSICHERUNG', 'VET', 'VG', 'VI', 'VIAJES', 'VIDEO', 'VIG', 'VIKING', 'VILLAS', 'VIN', 'VIP', 'VIRGIN', 'VISA', 'VISION', 'VIVA', 'VIVO', 'VLAANDEREN', 'VN', 'VODKA', 'VOLKSWAGEN', 'VOLVO', 'VOTE', 'VOTING', 'VOTO', 'VOYAGE', 'VU', 'VUELOS', 'WALES', 'WALMART', 'WALTER', 'WANG', 'WANGGOU', 'WATCH', 'WATCHES', 'WEATHER', 'WEATHERCHANNEL', 'WEBCAM', 'WEBER', 'WEBSITE', 'WED', 'WEDDING', 'WEIBO', 'WEIR', 'WF', 'WHOSWHO', 'WIEN', 'WIKI', 'WILLIAMHILL', 'WIN', 'WINDOWS', 'WINE', 'WINNERS', 'WME', 'WOLTERSKLUWER', 'WOODSIDE', 'WORK', 'WORKS', 'WORLD', 'WOW', 'WS', 'WTC', 'WTF', 'XBOX', 'XEROX', 'XFINITY', 'XIHUAN', 'XIN', 'XN--11B4C3D', 'XN--1CK2E1B', 'XN--1QQW23A', 'XN--2SCRJ9C', 'XN--30RR7Y', 'XN--3BST00M', 'XN--3DS443G', 'XN--3E0B707E', 'XN--3HCRJ9C', 'XN--3PXU8K', 'XN--42C2D9A', 'XN--45BR5CYL', 'XN--45BRJ9C', 'XN--45Q11C', 'XN--4DBRK0CE', 'XN--4GBRIM', 'XN--54B7FTA0CC', 'XN--55QW42G', 'XN--55QX5D', 'XN--5SU34J936BGSG', 'XN--5TZM5G', 'XN--6FRZ82G', 'XN--6QQ986B3XL', 'XN--80ADXHKS', 'XN--80AO21A', 'XN--80AQECDR1A', 'XN--80ASEHDB', 'XN--80ASWG', 'XN--8Y0A063A', 'XN--90A3AC', 'XN--90AE', 'XN--90AIS', 'XN--9DBQ2A', 'XN--9ET52U', 'XN--9KRT00A', 'XN--B4W605FERD', 'XN--BCK1B9A5DRE4C', 'XN--C1AVG', 'XN--C2BR7G', 'XN--CCK2B3B', 'XN--CCKWCXETD', 'XN--CG4BKI', 'XN--CLCHC0EA0B2G2A9GCD', 'XN--CZR694B', 'XN--CZRS0T', 'XN--CZRU2D', 'XN--D1ACJ3B', 'XN--D1ALF', 'XN--E1A4C', 'XN--ECKVDTC9D', 'XN--EFVY88H', 'XN--FCT429K', 'XN--FHBEI', 'XN--FIQ228C5HS', 'XN--FIQ64B', 'XN--FIQS8S', 'XN--FIQZ9S', 'XN--FJQ720A', 'XN--FLW351E', 'XN--FPCRJ9C3D', 'XN--FZC2C9E2C', 'XN--FZYS8D69UVGM', 'XN--G2XX48C', 'XN--GCKR3F0F', 'XN--GECRJ9C', 'XN--GK3AT1E', 'XN--H2BREG3EVE', 'XN--H2BRJ9C', 'XN--H2BRJ9C8C', 'XN--HXT814E', 'XN--I1B6B1A6A2E', 'XN--IMR513N', 'XN--IO0A7I', 'XN--J1AEF', 'XN--J1AMH', 'XN--J6W193G', 'XN--JLQ480N2RG', 'XN--JVR189M', 'XN--KCRX77D1X4A', 'XN--KPRW13D', 'XN--KPRY57D', 'XN--KPUT3I', 'XN--L1ACC', 'XN--LGBBAT1AD8J', 'XN--MGB9AWBF', 'XN--MGBA3A3EJT', 'XN--MGBA3A4F16A', 'XN--MGBA7C0BBN0A', 'XN--MGBAAKC7DVF', 'XN--MGBAAM7A8H', 'XN--MGBAB2BD', 'XN--MGBAH1A3HJKRD', 'XN--MGBAI9AZGQP6J', 'XN--MGBAYH7GPA', 'XN--MGBBH1A', 'XN--MGBBH1A71E', 'XN--MGBC0A9AZCG', 'XN--MGBCA7DZDO', 'XN--MGBCPQ6GPA1A', 'XN--MGBERP4A5D4AR', 'XN--MGBGU82A', 'XN--MGBI4ECEXP', 'XN--MGBPL2FH', 'XN--MGBT3DHD', 'XN--MGBTX2B', 'XN--MGBX4CD0AB', 'XN--MIX891F', 'XN--MK1BU44C', 'XN--MXTQ1M', 'XN--NGBC5AZD', 'XN--NGBE9E0A', 'XN--NGBRX', 'XN--NODE', 'XN--NQV7F', 'XN--NQV7FS00EMA', 'XN--NYQY26A', 'XN--O3CW4H', 'XN--OGBPF8FL', 'XN--OTU796D', 'XN--P1ACF', 'XN--P1AI', 'XN--PGBS0DH', 'XN--PSSY2U', 'XN--Q7CE6A', 'XN--Q9JYB4C', 'XN--QCKA1PMC', 'XN--QXA6A', 'XN--QXAM', 'XN--RHQV96G', 'XN--ROVU88B', 'XN--RVC1E0AM3E', 'XN--S9BRJ9C', 'XN--SES554G', 'XN--T60B56A', 'XN--TCKWE', 'XN--TIQ49XQYJ', 'XN--UNUP4Y', 'XN--VERMGENSBERATER-CTB', 'XN--VERMGENSBERATUNG-PWB', 'XN--VHQUV', 'XN--VUQ861B', 'XN--W4R85EL8FHU5DNRA', 'XN--W4RS40L', 'XN--WGBH1C', 'XN--WGBL6A', 'XN--XHQ521B', 'XN--XKC2AL3HYE2A', 'XN--XKC2DL3A5EE0H', 'XN--Y9A3AQ', 'XN--YFRO4I67O', 'XN--YGBI2AMMX', 'XN--ZFR164B', 'XXX', 'XYZ', 'YACHTS', 'YAHOO', 'YAMAXUN', 'YANDEX', 'YE', 'YODOBASHI', 'YOGA', 'YOKOHAMA', 'YOU', 'YOUTUBE', 'YT', 'YUN', 'ZA', 'ZAPPOS', 'ZARA', 'ZERO', 'ZIP', 'ZM', 'ZONE', 'ZUERICH', 'ZW']

function cleanTld(s) {
  let i = s.lastIndexOf('.');
  if(!i) return s; // no tld found
  let tld = s.substring(i+1).toUpperCase();
  if(tlds.includes(tld)) return s; // tld is OK
  let longestTldMatch = tlds.filter(t=>tld.startsWith(t)).sort((a,b)=>a.length-b.length).pop();
  if(!longestTldMatch) return s; // no matching tld found
  return s.substring(0, i+1) + longestTldMatch.toLowerCase();
}

console.log(cleanTld('aa@aaa.'))
console.log(cleanTld('aa@aaa'))
console.log(cleanTld('aa@aaa.comwww'))
console.log(cleanTld('aa@aaa.com'))
console.log(cleanTld('aa@aaa.xcom'))
console.log(cleanTld('aa@aaa.co.ukwww'))
console.log(cleanTld('aa@aaa.ly'))
console.log(cleanTld('aa@aaa.lyuuu'))
```

Comment: The list of TLDs may very well change in the future, hardcoding it is not a good solution.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie I agree, the ideal solution would be to load the IANA URL contents periodically into a file, and then use that cached data. That's something that would need to be done server-side.

Comment: Also this approach is doomed to failure. For instance your list of TLD contains `BB` and `BBVA`. How would you decide whether `foo@example.bbvalue` should be reduced to `@example.bb` or `@example.bbva`? You might say "Take the longer one", but I guarantee you, there will be cases where this is wrong ...

Comment: @derpirscher I agree, there is no perfect way to clean an email. If they miss out the `m` in `.com`, then `.co` is a valid TLD too. However, my approach is non-destructive. As long as the TLD data from IANA is up-to-date, it will never remove characters from a valid email address. I don't see any reason to avoid making best efforts to clean up an email address when the TLD is definitely invalid. The possibility of success is better than the guarantee of failure.

Comment: @AndrewParks there is no real need for such effort. If the email is already wrong, trying to "correct" it is just bad form in many ways. At the very least, it might actually give you a correct email address... for somebody completely different. So, the best effort now starts sending unsolicited emails. And *yes*, a person can also misspell their email as somebody else's (believe me, I've a decade-long war against at least two people who keep mistyping their emails as mine...) but that's different from a system asserting an email is different when it knows it's wrong.

Comment: @VLAZ I agree with you. I'd say the best solution is to simply alert the user when the email address is definitely invalid, and ask the user to correct it instead of guessing. I'm simply answering the question as asked. My code would be useful for a "did you mean..." error message.